# How to permanently set X display to be rotated?

Tags: display-rotation, xorg.conf

I'm trying to configure Ubuntu 20.04 with X to be always in portrait mode. I can get display rotation to work per-monitor basis using ~/.config/monitors.xml, but this file requires settings per monitor and per connection (HDMI or VGA).

Is there a way to set display rotation systemwide and independent of the monitor and output port used?

For example, if I use one monitor to configure display rotation and later replace it with another monitor, the display rotation configuration won't apply.

Tried adding 10-monitors.config to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ with these settings:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI-1"
    Option "Rotate" "right"
EndSection
```

But this didn't have any effect.

Tried generating xorg.conf to /etc/X11/xorg.conf and adding Option "Rotate" "right". This didn't work either.

Using Xorg and GDM. It is fine to change to another.

Thank you for any suggestions.